# vscode не находит место определения

Tags: javascript, html5, visual-studio-code

Такая история.

У меня есть HTML файл, к нему подключен CSS файл и ещё несколько JS файлов.
И вот я нажимаю на идентификаторе или классе правой кнопкой мыши нажимаю "перейти к определению" и мне пишет "определение для (имя класса) не найдено", так же он мне выдаёт когда я хочу перейти к месту определения функции.

То есть VsCode не может найти в подключенных файлах место определения функции, класса, ID итд. Так сам редактор устроен или есть какое-то решение?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code не умеет ориентироваться таким образом по css и js файлам.

Если хотите так искать все ссылки на js функции, то надо писать на typescript и работать с ним, а потом транспиллировать в js.

Comment: Кстати как только я этот вопрос написал нашёл частичное решение, почему до написания вопроса ничего такого не находилось.(
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek
Но эта история помогает только для HTML - CSS. А для нахождения JS функций подобного расширения не нашёл.